# jump to another page when the submit button is click and save the cookies

Tags: javascript

hye guys, i am new to the javascript, i suppose to make some webs to collect info from the user, what i have now is some textbox and i want people click the submit button and go to another page, with all the data saved as cookies. but i think i get stuck when i try jump to another page. The code i have now is below:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function submit()
 var fName = document.form[0].firstName.value;
 var lName = document.form[0].lastName.value;
 var addone = document.form[0].streetAddone.value;
 var addtwo = document.form[0].streetAddtwo.value;
 var city = document.form[0].city.value;
 var state = document.form[0].state.value;
 var zip = document.form[0].zip.value;
 var phone = document.form[0].phone.value;
 var fax = document.form[0].fax.value;
 var expireDate = new Date();
   myDate.setFullYear(myDate.getFullyear() + 1);
     document.cookie = "firstName" +encodeURIComponent(fName) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = "lastName" +encodeURIComponent(lName) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = "streetAddone" +encodeURIComponent(addone) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = "streetAddtwo" +encodeURIComponent(addtwo) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = "city" +encodeURIComponent(city) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = "state" +encodeURIComponent(state) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = "zip" +encodeURIComponent(zip) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = "phone" +encodeURIComponent(phone) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = "fax" +encodeURIComponent(fax) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
      location.href = "Record.html";
```

HTML part:

```
<form action="" method="get">


First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName">
Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastName"><br>

Street address 1:<input type="text" name="streetAddone"><br>

Street address 2:<input type="text" name="streetAddtwo"><br>


city:<input type="text" name="city">
State:<input type="text" name="state">
Zip:<input type="text" name="zip"><br>


Phone:<input type="text" name="phone"><br>
Fax:<input type="text" name="fax">


<input type="submit" name="carType" value="Submit Reservation" onclick="submitForm()"> </input>
</form>
```

i know that add the page name to the form action will work, but i want to know if the location will work or not?How can i get it to work?

(PS: sorry my code is little mess..)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Added a better event handling method with `addEvent()` at the beginning to help with browser compatibility if you're worried about that.

---

### Ditch the `<form>` entirely

Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

You can select the `<input>` elements' values with `document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value` and then get the button with an id selector of course - `document.getElementById('button-id')`.

*you have a few more little mistakes/typos/lazies in the code and since this is such a change from what you have I went ahead and just find/replaced what you needed cuz I'm OCD but left the irrelevant stuff unchanged.*

## [working example for you](http://jsfiddle.net/harvugnm/4/)

**Code:**

```
First Name:
<input type="text" name="firstName" />
Last Name:
<input type="text" name="lastName" />
<br>Street address 1:
<input type="text" name="streetAddone" />
<br>Street address 2:
<input type="text" name="streetAddtwo" />
<br>City:
<input type="text" name="city" />State:
<input type="text" name="state" />Zip:
<input type="text" name="zip" />
<br>Phone:
<input type="text" name="phone" />
<br>Fax:
<input type="text" name="fax" />
<input type="button" id="carType" value="Submit Reservation" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addEvent(element, myEvent, fnc) {
        return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
    };
    addEvent(document.getElementById('carType'), "click", function() {
        var fName = document.getElementsByName('firstName')[0].value;
        var lName = document.getElementsByName('lastName')[0].value;
        var addone = document.getElementsByName('streetAddone')[0].value;
        var addtwo = document.getElementsByName('streetAddtwo')[0].value;
        var city = document.getElementsByName('city')[0].value;
        var state = document.getElementsByName('state')[0].value;
        var zip = document.getElementsByName('zip')[0].value;
        var phone = document.getElementsByName('phone')[0].value;
        var fax = document.getElementsByName('fax')[0].value;
        var expireDate = new Date(Date.now());
        expireDate.setFullYear(expireDate.getFullYear() + 1);
        document.cookie = "firstName" + encodeURIComponent(fName) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "lastName" + encodeURIComponent(lName) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "streetAddone" + encodeURIComponent(addone) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "streetAddtwo" + encodeURIComponent(addtwo) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "city" + encodeURIComponent(city) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "state" + encodeURIComponent(state) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "zip" + encodeURIComponent(zip) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "phone" + encodeURIComponent(phone) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "fax" + encodeURIComponent(fax) + "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString();
        return window.location.href = "Record.html";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hey man i just change the code and try a different way, but is still not work, i edit my post. Do you know why that happened this time?

Comment: `onclick="submitForm()"` maybe try `onclick="submit()"`

Comment: you can even do `onclick="submit();return false"` or `onsubmit="submit();return false"`

Comment: still didn't work, do i need a function to let it turn to next page?

Comment: see new answer for better method.  adjust as needed.